# EPplus Add Column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, epplus

Question, how can i add additional column in EPplus, im using LoadFromCollection?

Example: 
in my File Model, here are the columns: **Name, FirstName, LastName, Birthday** but i want to add an additional column which is a drop down named:

- **Update (Yes/No)**

and it will look like this:
Name, FirstName, LastName, Update, Birthday

```
            //Sheet
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = excel.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("File");
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(File, true);

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=File.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
```

Comment: Why not simply added the column?  You can determine how many are written by LoadFromCollection by using Reflections to look at the File object.  And you know how my entries (rows) are in File.  Then just do the math.

Comment: did you use `workSheet.InsertColumn` ?

Answer (score 9):

You can simply put a column by using the following format:

```
workSheet.InsertColumn(33, 1);
```

33 is the starting position of the column and 1 represents the number of columns you need.